# Outlook 365 inbox rule to redirect emails not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, exchange, redirection

I am experiencing a problem with Outlook 365. Please read/follow the following steps to replicate the problem:

1. Create a regular user account (alpha@example.org)
2. Create a shared user account (beta@example.org)
3. In the shared user account *beta* create an inbox rule that all messages will be **redirected** to user *alpha*.

IMPORTANT: Be sure to use the redirection option in the mailbox rule, no forwarding option.

---

Testing:

1. Send a test message from inside of the organization account (gama@example.org) to *beta*
2. Send a test message from outside of the organization account (delta@???.org) to *beta*
3. Send a test message from *alpha* to *beta*

---

Results:

1. The test message has been delivered to *beta*'s inbox as well as to *alpha*'s inbox.
2. The test message has been delivered to *beta*'s inbox as well as to *alpha*'s inbox.
3. The test message has been delivered to *beta*'s inbox only.

---

Conclusion:

It is unexpected behavior that message sent from *alpha* to *beta* is not redirected by the *beta*'s inbox rule. Why is this happening? There is no loop that would prevent the redirection being processed. How can be this fixed?

Comment: I reached your question as I had the same behavior with Office 365 Exchange rules and sending emails from PHPMailer through our relay. In our case, another rule with higher priority had the `Stop processing more rules` option checked so the rule to redirect  never ran.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is by design. I tested a lot in my Outlook and got the same situation as you. Tring to found some documents to explain this, but could not found any information.

Comment: By design... Intentionally? Or is it a bug? I hope there is some known workaround for this problem.

Comment: Did lots of research but seems have no other workaround for it so far. The same rule work the same on the web mail.